# Master-Master replication auto_increment_offset

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-master-replication

I have set up 2 MYSQL servers:

my.cnf server1:

```
auto_increment_increment = 2
auto_increment_offset = 1
```

my.cnf server2:

```
auto_increment_increment = 2
auto_increment_offset = 2
```

But when I insert records one by one 10 times from different servers:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `text`) VALUES (NULL, '22222');
```

Result:

```
id  text
1   22222
2   22222
5   22222
6   22222
9   22222
...
```

But I want to:

```
id  text
1   22222
2   22222
3   22222
4   22222
5   22222
...
```

It is possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Partial reason for this could be because the inserts are invoked from separate sessions. With auto_increment_increment = 2, my guess is you will probably not get your desired result. Did you try setting both auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset to 1?

Comment: doing so will create a potential conflict risk.